# CertificateValidationUnsupported using oauth2/httplib2 on Python 2.4

Tags: python, django, ssl, oauth-2.0, httplib2

At a first look, python-ouath2 seemed to have many problems with Python 2.4, so I managed to get a patch on that by *Googling*.
But I'm still getting an error from httplib2 as follows:

> CertificateValidationUnsupported:
>   SSL certificate validation is not supported without the ssl module installed. To avoid this error, install the ssl module, or explicity disable validation.

I've done a lot of research on installing that ssl module but I can't find anything useful.

I'm using a web host running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 and I only have the SSH access to my account but with no further writing privileges beyond my folders.
Tryied to install SSL from easy_install but it asked for another lib called libssl-dev and I couldn't manage to install it without the "apt-get" command which I can't use.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you been able to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python 2.3-2.5, you need to install the [ssl module from PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl). If you have [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) installed, you should be able to just do `easy_install ssl`. The documentation for the library is the [Python ssl docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html), there are no separate docs for the external version.

Comment: I tryied to install it but I'm getting a error "No SSL support found". Then, I've discovered I had to install libss1-dev but I can't use apt-get to do so.

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information, your operating system, and any other relevant info. I'll take a look again a bit later.

Comment: I added all the information I think that could be relevant and which steps I took. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it if you don't have root privileges. The easiest way is certainly to ask the administrator to install `libssl-dev` and tell him you need it for Python's SSL support. Otherwise, you may need to install Python 2.6 or newer in your home directory and use that instead of the system Python.